# How do I increase horizontal space between my list?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to increase the space in my inline list so that they are not stuck side by side. I have tried word spacing and adding padding to the header a links, but that hasn't worked. Also, I found the only way to make my list in order (shop, products, faq, blog) inline and floating in the centre is to put the list backwards. So when I do

blog

faq

products

shop

it will show up in the order as shop, products, faq blog. I was wondering if there was a way to be able to write them in html in order and still have them display inline in order. Any help is appreciated, thanks! BTW I have

```
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}
```

already

```css
#header-flex {
      display: flex;
      position: fixed;
      background: rgb(0,191,255);
      height: 75px;
      width: 100%;

    }

    header a {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }

    header li a:hover {
      color: orange;
      cursor: grabbing;
    }

    nav p a:hover {
      color: orange;
      cursor: grabbing;
    }

    .left, .mid, .right {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <nav id="header-flex">

        <div class="left">
          <img src="logo.jpg" alt=logo width="30px" height="30px">
        </div>

        <div class="mid">
          <ul>
            <li ><a href="___">Blog</a></li>
            <li ><a href="___">FAQ</a></li>
            <li ><a href="___">Products</a></li>
            <li ><a href="___">Shop</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <p><a href="___">Sign In</a></p>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: try `clear:both` for `header li`

Comment: it puts them in the correct order, but takes out the inline block

Comment: You are using a list with the `<ul>` tag, which stands for **unordered** list. Try replacing it for `<ol>`, and writing the elements in the order you want them. At least the ordering should be solved.

Comment: You're floating your links to the right, that's why they appear in reverse order. If you float them to the left they will appear in order.

Comment: <ol> still puts them in a backwards order

Comment: Thanks CrisD that works, to place my div's where I want them on the horizontal line as in logo, list, and sign in, should I use padding or margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below updated snippet code

```css
#header-flex {
      display: flex;
      position: fixed;
      background: rgb(0,191,255);
      height: 75px;
      width: 100%;

    }

    header a {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }

    header li a:hover {
      color: orange;
      cursor: grabbing;
    }

    nav p a:hover {
      color: orange;
      cursor: grabbing;
    }

    .left, .right {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }

    .mid {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .mid ul{
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .mid ul li{
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

   .mid ul li a{
        float: none;
        padding: 0 6px;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <nav id="header-flex">

        <div class="left">
          <img src="logo.jpg" alt=logo width="30px" height="30px">
        </div>

        <div class="mid">
          <ul>
            <li ><a href="___">Shop</a></li>
            <li ><a href="___">Products</a></li>
            <li ><a href="___">FAQ</a></li>
            <li ><a href="___">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <p><a href="___">Sign In</a></p>
        </div>

      </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write like this if you need another order?

```
<div class="mid">
      <ul>
        <li ><a href="___">Shop</a></li>
        <li ><a href="___">Products</a></li>
        <li ><a href="___">FAQ</a></li>
        <li ><a href="___">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

or there is something I didn`t get

and for horizontal space do this

```
.mid li {padding: 0px, 10px,0px,10px;}
```